# Azure webapps on linux python redirect naked to www

Tags: python, azure, redirect

I have a python App Service on Linux in Azure with a custom domain and https.
The https is on the www domain only.
How can I redirect the naked domain request to www in https?
for example https://domainname.com to https://www.domainname.com

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution but I have a plan. I check the request at the application level and redirect to www if the domain doesn't begin with the www.